# Show that by a translation poles on the boundary of an elliptic curve can be avoided.

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

In *Complex Analysis* by Freitag it is claimed that if there are poles on the boundary of an elliptic curve (the parallelogram) can be avoided by a-translation.

Is there any simple but rigorous proof for this. Even considering a geometrical proof (perhaps not a rigorous proof), I can't figure that out because of dealing with 4 lines of the boundary simultaneously.

Comment: If $f$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z})$ then it has finitely many zeros/poles and there are finitely many $u,v \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(z+u+v \tau)$ has some zeros/poles on $\mathbb{R} +\Lambda\ \ \cup\ \  \tau \mathbb{R} +\Lambda$

Comment: Still no simple understandable answer..